# Does the word relitigate imply legal proceedings?

Tags: meaning, geography

I understand the word, "litigate" to indicate some kind of legal action. However, I have recently come across the word "re-litigate" in a context that implies a difference of opinion that has not (yet?) become a matter for the courts.

- Is a non-legal sense of "re-litigate" common usage?

I've lived all my life in the UK, but to my recollection, I have not heard the word before.

- Is usage of the the word "re-litigate" more common outside the UK? In the US, for example?

Comment: It just means "litigate again". In a context where _litigate_ implies legal proceedings, so does _re-litigate_; if not, not.

Comment: Your title appears to be asking a slightly different question to the body.

Answer (score 4):

Not a common usage, probably based on sense of [litigate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/litigate): (archaic) : Dispute. (M-W)

[Relitigate:](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/relitigate)
(transitive) To dispute, debate, contest again.

> 2010, Lexington, The Economist, 5 Aug 2010:
>   *Like Mr bin Laden, Mr Gingrich is apparently still relitigating the victories and defeats of religious wars fought in Europe and the Middle East centuries ago*.

(Wiktionary)

Comment: Synonymous to 'appealing judgement' then?